# Did a boy die after masturbating 42 times?

Tags: biology, masturbation

Some years ago, there were reports being over social networks and blogs that "a boy died after masturbating 42 times in a row".

For example: [M24 Digital](http://m24digital.com/unusual-boy-dies-after-masturbating-42-times/):

> A 16-year-old boy died after masturbating 42 times without stopping in Rubiato town, in Goiás region, Brazil.

Is this story true? Is it even possible for someone to masturbate 42 times in a single day?

Comment: 42 is a very special number.

Comment: How do you define "masturbate 42 times"? When does one time end and the next time begin?

Comment: Did he keep a log? Invited spectators perhaps?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The Big Bang Theory reference. :P

Comment: H2G2 reference first. Its the number, not what you do with it...

Comment: So it was 42 times over the course of .... a night?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Snopes did a fact check](https://www.snopes.com/teen-boy-46-times/) and found that a recent variant of this story, set in Detroit - which they say was derived from the older Brazilian version - was false.

They questioned how anyone knew the exact number of times that boy pleasured himself before dying.

> Like similar dubious claims, the story had plenty of holes (such as the question of **precisely how anyone might have known how many times the boy pleasured himself before suddenly expiring**). Now44News appears to be the newest version of known hoax purveyor Now8News, with an identical interface and similar style of content.

Comment: [I guess it is 36](https://richhillenjr.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/masturbation-world-record/).

Comment: @AJ: Read further down--that's the *former* world record.